# How to retain css formatting in clipboard?

Tags: html, css, formatting

A website has many lines, each formatted as follows:

```
<p>
  <span class="time">08:52:33</span>
  <span class="context">xxx</span>
  <span class="message">...</span>
</p>
```

Through css positions of the different classes it looks alligned in columns when viewed in browser. Something like:

```
08:52:33  xxx    ...
08:52:33  y      .....
```

When copied to clipboard and pasted to a texteditor each line gets merged into a single unreadable character sequence.

```
08:52:33xxx...
```

How can be some characters (tabs seem ideal) inserted into the copied text as to have it formatted when pasted in eg. notepad, without disturbing the web layout?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. You are asking how can I render `html` and `css` content without either one. It would have to be passed inside a script while the pasting is happening.

Comment: I look at it differently: How to add plaintext formatting to the html without affecting the visual appearance of the rendered page...?

Comment: You are talking about something like a flat file that is generated on pasting.